# Identify PCB component

Tags: identification

Last week my living room thermostat "exploded" when adjusting the room temperature. Well, something inside sounded like exploding and since then it behaves erratically: the measured temperature shows 40 degrees C and the temperature-setting goes up and down automatically.

I'm trying to fix it now, and the only components that could possibly have exploded are shown in the picture:

[image]

Two parallel coin-cell-like capacitors I suppose (also considering the marking C21 and C22,) which seem to have a brown-ish smudge around the bottom. The marking shows "113N".

Before I start removing it, what are C21 and C22 and what special properties does it have? What should it be replaced with?
The thermostat is a Honeywell opentherm modulation touch 4T40.

Comment: Possibly a super-capacitor, however the "coin cell" shape is standard for batteries also.

Comment: In my limited experience, there typically isn't enough energy in a thermostat circuit to cause a satisfying 'exploding effect'. Maybe a better description of the event, and more thermostat pics would bring to light other possibilities than just the super caps (which to me look kinda fine from the outside).  Any recent home renovations?  Any new mirrors or pictures hung?  Meteor strikes?

Comment: They don't look like exploded. And there likely are other components as well that could have exploded. Fixing something means you must first be sure what to fix.

Comment: maybe the thermostat entered "demo mode" of some kind ... the sound may even be unrelated

Comment: There would be black marks/ashes in case something exploded. Also note that when IC go poof they can make a fairly spectacular lighting effect and still look mostly intact afterwards, except for a little hole in the package somewhere. I think you should examine the board more carefully. If there was an actual 'bang' then yeah there isn't likely anything but caps on the PCB that can cause it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the PCB, they appear to be wired in parallel. That's a little odd for batteries - you'd just use a bigger battery. They've been spot-welded so you can't replace them like a battery when it's run-out.

So, yes, super capacitors like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10317) or [this](https://www.ebay.com.sg/itm/185376121677).

The thermostat has a clock so the super capacitor probably keeps it running when power fails. That implies you can just remove them and it will all work fine - until the power fails.

If/when you replace them, the capacitance won't matter much but measure the voltage with a meter. Some super capacitors can take 3.3V and some 5V.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that makes sense. In fact, I've looked for supercapacitors, but couldn't find anything resembling the ones in the links you provide.

Comment: @SamBalby You'll have to know the exact part including voltage ratings and ESR. Otherwise don't bother, replace the whole thing.

Comment: I'm not convinced ESR matters here. It matters in, e.g., a smoothing cap but maybe not here. If it's to back-up the clock during power-outage then the current is going to be very low. ESR won't matter.  What else is it likely to be used for here?